# In case of 0 query result, response is not proper in php

Tags: php

URL in php

```
$app->post('/validate_coupon', 'authenticate', function() use ($app) {

    global $user_id;
    $response = array();
    verifyRequiredParams(array('couponcode'));

    $couponcode = $app->request->post('couponcode');


    $db = new DbHandler();

        if($data = $db->getCouponDetail($user_id, $couponcode)){
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "Query successful.";
            $response['data'] = $data;
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        }
        else{
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Unknown error occured while fetching coupon detail.";
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        }

});
```

Calling function from url

```
public function getCouponDetail($user_id, $couponCode){
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT order_id FROM table_orders O INNER JOIN table_customers C on C.customer_id = O.customer_id WHERE O.coupon_code = :couponCode AND C.customer_id = :customerId";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("couponCode", $couponCode);
        $stmt->bindParam("customerId", $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($result != 0){
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        elseif ($result == 0) {
            $result = array();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

In this function if result row count is not 0, it gives out like this.

```
{
  "error": false,
  "message": "Query successful.",
  "data": [
    {
      "order_id": "2183"
    }
  ]
}
```

But if result row count is 0, i got

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "Unknown error occured while fetching coupon detail."
}
```

I want

```
{
  "error": false,
  "message": "Query successful.",
  "data": [
    {
      "order_id": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

What should i change in calling function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ([])` if of empty array will always false that's why you are getting else message

If you want message as you said you should return same thing here instead of empty array

```
if ($result != 0){
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        elseif ($result == 0) {
            $result = ['order_id' => 0];
        }
```